# How to select a random value from a collection in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, random, plsql

I have a collection full of data
how to select a random data from there?

```
declare
TYPE r_emp_id IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
    emps r_emp_id;
begin
select employes_id into emps from employes order by employes_id;

for i in <(random number of employes_id from emps)> loop

DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(employes_id (i)); 
end loop;
end;
```

Comment: `table of number` is a nested table type, not an associative array. `table of number index by pls_integer` would be an associative array; you have nothing like that in your code. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to `BULK COLLECT INTO` a collection and then you don't want a loop if you just want a single random value:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE r_emp_id IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
  emps r_emp_id;
  i    PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT employes_id
  BULK COLLECT INTO emps
  FROM   employes
  ORDER BY employes_id;

  i := FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, emps.COUNT + 1));

  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(emps(i)); 
END;
/
```

If you want all the values in a random order then:

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE r_emp_id IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
  emps r_emp_id;
BEGIN
  SELECT employes_id
  BULK COLLECT INTO emps
  FROM   employes
  ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE;

  FOR i IN 1 .. emps.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(emps(i)); 
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

---

However, for a single value, you could skip the collection entirely:

```sql
DECLARE
  emp_id EMPLOYES.EMPLOYES_ID%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT employes_id
  INTO   emp_id
  FROM   employes
  ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
  FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(emp_id); 
END;
/
```

Or, in SQL (and not PL/SQL):

```sql
SELECT employes_id
FROM   employes
ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a5a4947935be8bd10fa33bf8a4c5a291)*